# System refuses to boot RHEL DVD, but will boot other distos

Tags: redhat, installation, boot-loader

I'm trying to install RHEL7 on a Dell R210.  The system was RHEL5, but had shred run against its disk.  I tried booting a DVD with the RHEL7 installer, but got nothing, it would not boot.  I've reburned the DVD twice with different burners, tried an old DVD with RHEL6 that has worked on other systems, redownloaded the iso and burned that, and even borrowed a USB drive, but nothing works.  I've gone through the boot loader and made sure it is using the DVD, still to no avail.  But the strangest part is that a CentOS7 and a Knoppix DVD work perfectly.  It seems to be versions of RHEL that are the issue.

How can this be?  What should I try?

Comment: What happens exactly when you try to boot from the media in question? What messages do you get?

Comment: @joeqwerty Now that I have CentOS on the system, it ignores the DVD and boots to the hard disk.  Prior, when there was nothing on the hard disk, it would advance to try and boot from the NIC.  No errors, it acts as if the RHEL DVD isn't there.

Comment: Check the checksum of your DVD image. You may have [downloaded the wrong image](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1373663).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Nope.  Checksum is correct.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're having problems with booting from the CD/DVD, correct? Will the CD/DVDs that you burned for RHEL6 and 7 load the installer on another system?

Comment: Perhaps it's a UEFI BIOS issue. Try updating the BIOS if possible and check other BIOS settings.

Comment: It sounds like a boot order problem to me, but requires more info. UEFI or BIOS? Any error messages? It sounds like this server currently has a working install of CentOS?

Comment: Try booting from a USB stick, or iDRAC virtual media.

Comment: Stupid question but did you try another DVD or were you reburning the same one?

Comment: @CIA The problem is not the DVD in general, but DVDs with Red Hat disto.

Comment: @AndreasTurriff Not a boot order problem, I've addressed that and even eliminated the hard disk and NIC.  In that case the DVD is still ignored if it is a Red Hat distro.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried a USB stick with a Red Hat distro and it too was ignored.

Comment: @MatthewIfe I've tried four different ISOs and three different DVD burners.

Comment: That's actually interesting, and not what I expected. About the only thing I can think of to suggest at this point, short of involving Dell's support, is to attempt to completely clear CMOS and reset any firmware to factory defaults.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search of the technical guide for the model shows: RHEL 7 is not in the supported OS list. Please have a look at it here, Table 25, page 54:
[Dell PowerEdge R210 Technical Guide](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/poweredge-r210-ii-technical-guide.pdf)

Or check here:
[Red Hat Enterprise Linux Certification Matrix for Dell PowerEdge Servers](http://linux.dell.com/files/supportmatrix/RHEL_Support_Matrix.pdf)

I would suggest to check the manual and use the manufacturer supplied deployment CD/DVD to install supported OS version.

Here is a lits of supported Dell Poweredge Model from Redhat: [Browse Certified Hardware](https://hardware.redhat.com/list.cgi?massquery=RHEL7&quicksearch=dell&showall=1)

Here is a link for OS installation:
[How to Install the Operating System on Dell PowerEdge 11G Servers](http://www.dell.com/support/Article/us/en/19/SLN129564/EN)

Comment: I have used the DVD which refuses to read on this box to install RHEL7 on an identical Dell R210.

Comment: Then I'd call Dell and have them fix the bad machine..

Comment: @dacracot, well, may be it's possible to install. But I'm only pointing at the fact that official reference says it's not supported. And there is always good reasons to take it into consideration. I personally would not recommend to install an OS which is not officially supported, even if it's possible to install on a production server. Of course you can contact Dell and ask for their advice or support.

Comment: @dacracot I have further edited the answer to add a list from Redhat site, which also shows the model is not supported by RHEL 7. To conclude, I recommend you to go through the knowledgebase article I have mentioned. Hope it will be of help.

Comment: @dacracot, about being able to install on an identical server, may be you can check whether the firmware and BIOS versions are also similar.

Comment: @dacracot, have you also tried to install it the way, as Dell suggests (press F10 at system boot and then proceed with OS deployment) ? (Link to dell site in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would install any distro (that uses GRUB), and set its GRUB to boot the RHEL 7 install, based on what is seen from item 7 (and on) here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-installation-server-setup.html

Another option is to create a usb drive to boot that ISO for you, using http://www.pendrivelinux.com

Comment: No Red Hat distro will boot for an install, including RHEL6.

Comment: Then install some other distro that uses GRUB and set it up to boot off of it.